# Parameters with dash not working when using Dailymotion javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, video, dailymotion-api

I have this embed code to create a simple player :

```
var player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"), {
video: "xp3omu",
  width: "480px",
  height: "360px",
  params: {
    start: 150,
    sharing-enable: false,
    queue-enable: false,
  }
});
```

Everytime I try to use parameters with dash as sharing-enable, queue-enable, ui-highlight etc I find that the player fail to load. 
The doc is here : https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#embedding

However when using the iframe tag, there is no problem :

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="360"
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xp3omu?start=150&sharing-enable=false&queue-enable=false" allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

What am I missing? Can anyone tell me if he has the same issues?

Comment: Thanks raina for your answer, it works perfectly now

Comment: If the answer is helpful, just accept it. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape those dashed words (wrap them in quotation marks):

```
params: {
  start: 150,
  'sharing-enable': false,
  'queue-enable': false,
}
```

... as only valid identifiers can be used directly (without wrapping them) as object literal keys, and `-` character cannot be a part of valid identifier in JS. By the way, console should probably show the helpful message here.